# "PerformSelector names a selector which retains the object" error and ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Ok with ARC how do we solve this gracefully?

The problem is the code created with WSDL2OBJC.. I fixed all other problems but this one eludes me..

```
if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(initWithCoder:)] && ![self isKindOfClass:[super class]]) {
    self = [super performSelector:@selector(initWithCoder:) withObject:decoder];
} else {
    self = [super init];
}
```

In WSDL2OBJC they resolved this problem here like this:

"In Targets->Build Phases-> Compile Sources
For all the wsdl2objc sources add: -fno-obcj-arc"

But this is actually not a fix on the code.. Only prevents ARC on WSDL2OBJC sources..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to give up ARC on WSDL2OBJC and use compiler flag

Answer (score 2):

try this solution:

```
self = [super performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"initWithCoder:") withObject:aDecoder];
```

Comment: Bypassing the error like this simply produces memory leaks in ARC.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the superclass, can’t you simply drop this mess and call the appropriate initializer directly?

Comment: Well the superclass is dynamically provided, so there's no possible solution there..